# Makefile Linux how to execute function for each variable

Tags: linux, makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I am trying to setup a Makefile with dependencies. The dependencies are specified in a variable.

```
MATH_VER=1.1
EXTERNAL_DEPS=MATH GC LOG
```

I want it to run a function that tries to figure out the location of each of the external libs based on whats available.
So I added a rule setversion,

```
all:setversion myexe
setversion:
     $(foreach CHKLIB, $(EXTERNAL_DEPS), $(call checklib, $(CHKLIB)))
```

I have the function that does the checking

```
checklib = ifeq ($(wildcard $(ROOT)/$(var)/$(var)_VER),)
echo 'Bad dir'
$(var)_ROOT=$SOMEOTHERDIR
else
echo 'Good dir'
$(var)_ROOR=$(ROOT)/$(var)/$(var)_VER
endif
```

This dosent work - but I think it gives a good idea of what Im looking for. Can anyone point me to how this can be accomplished?
Thanks

Comment: Sooner or later you are going to need autotools, why not start learning now: http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html

Comment: Do you want to use the variables `whatever_ROOT` outside the `setversion` rule?

Comment: yes MATH_ROOT gets used when building the exec

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I tested this out on my system and it seemed to do what you need.

```
define set_deps
        ifeq ($(wildcard $(ROOT)/$(1)/$($(1)_VER)/),)
                $(1)_ROOT=$(DEFAULT_DIR)
        else
                $(1)_ROOT=$(ROOT)/$(1)/$($(1)_VER)/
        endif
endef


$(foreach lib, $(EXTERNAL_DEPS), $(eval $(call set_deps,$(lib))))

$(foreach lib, $(EXTERNAL_DEPS), $(eval $(info $(lib) => $($(lib)_ROOT))))
```

Make sure to check out the [documentation for the eval function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html).

Also, if you wanted to match against a list of possible directories you could use the following.

```
 define set_deps
     $(1)_ROOT = $(firstword $(wildcard $(ROOT)/$(1)/$($(1)_VER)/) $(DEFAULT_DIR))
 endef
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But do you add this in the command section for "setversion", or before you get to the commands. I added this before, and it works but then I try to do a conditional exit or print and it seems to print all the time. Ex: I added $(info WARN Missing dir) in the else section but it prints always regardless of the condition. I added a "exit" and it never exits

Comment: I had intended for this to be used instead of the `setversion` command. 

Also, I think something far more strange is occuring with the $(info) printing regardless of condition: if you use the alternative if syntax `$(1)_ROOT=$(if $(wildcard $(ROOT)/$(1)/$($(1)_VER)/), $(ROOT)/$(1)/$($(1)_VER)/$(info hello), $(DEFAULT_DIR)$(info world))` you see that only one branch is evaluated, rather than both with the current syntax. My guess is the conditional make interprets both branches, or we found a bug.

Comment: I should warn you that further questions will lead you to the weird, dark part of make from which there is no return. Proceed with extreme caution.

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function) might help:

Note that in the example, the result of the foreach call is what is stored, not the side-effects of calling each function in the foreach loop.